# When can I start using properties set using UIAppearance?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiappearance

I have some custom appearance properties in my view class (a descendant of `UIView`). I want to customize the view appearance according to these properties, but I can’t do that inside the initializer, since the values set using `[[MyClass appearance] setFoo:…]` aren’t in effect at that point:

```
@interface View : UIView
@property(strong) UIColor *someColor UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
@end

@implementation View
@synthesize someColor;

// Somewhere in other code before the initializer is called:
// [[View appearance] setSomeColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

- (id) initWithFrame: (CGRect) frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    NSLog(@"%@", someColor); // nil
    return self;
}

@end
```

They are already set in `layoutSubviews`, but that’s not a good point to perform the view customizations, since some customizations may trigger `layoutSubviews` again, leading to an endless loop.

So, what’s a good point to perform the customizations? Or is there a way to trigger the code that applies the appearance values?

Comment: I think once the custom class has been allocated , the properties of member can always be accessed and changed as per requirement and then the object can be used with the modified information in the code.

Comment: Just to make sure, I am talking about the properties set through the appearance proxy (`UIAppearance`). These values are set somewhere later than in the initializer. If I set a breakpoint on the property setter, I can see that the values are applied from `[CALayer layoutSublayers]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible workaround is to grab the value directly from the proxy:

```
- (id) initWithFrame: (CGRect) frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    NSLog(@"%@", [[View appearance] someColor); // not nil
    return self;
}
```

Of course this kills the option to vary the appearance according to the view container and is generally ugly. Second option I found is to perform the customizations in the setter:

```
- (void) setSomeColor: (UIColor*) newColor
{
    someColor = newColor;
    // do whatever is needed
}
```

Still I’d rather have some hook that gets called after the appearance properties are set.

Comment: see my answer; the 'hook' is UIView didMoveToSuperview:, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Why not wait until

```
- (void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview {
    [super willMoveToSuperview:newSuperview];

    if (newSuperview) {
        ... code here ...
    }
}
```

if it's giving you trouble?

Comment: That was my next attempt, but the values are not set at that point either.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `UIAppearance` properties are applied to a view when it is being added into a view hierarchy.  So presumably you could access the set properties in `UIView didMoveToSuperview`.

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: I am using Swift 2, so not sure about earlier versions of Swift / Objective-C. But I have found that `didMoveToSuperview()` will not work. The properties are available in `layoutSubviews()`, but that's not a great place to do anything like this (since it can be called more than once). The best place to access these properties in the lifeCycle of the view I have found is `didMoveToWindow()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that viewDidLoad would be best if it's a one-time thing. Otherwise, viewWillAppear.

EDIT:

If you want to do it in the view, and not it's controller then I would create a custom init for the view along the lines of:

```
-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect) frame andAppearanceColor:(UIColor)theColor;
```

thereby passing the colour into the view at creation time.

Comment: These are controller methods and I’d much rather handle it in the view. Besides, it’s quite probable that the values are not set yet during these calls.

Comment: Passing the color in the initializer is also not an option, since there are more appearance properties to set and the initializer is called in a place out of the controller’s… erm, *control*. One could say that the whole point of the appearance proxy API was to get rid of setting the values by hand all the time.

Comment: I see where you're coming from. Maybe you could create a method to set the appearance properties and call it in response to an NSNotification (sent when the appearance properties are specified)?

Comment: At the time when the appearance properties are set through `[[View appearance] setSomeColor:…]`, the instances of `View` don’t exist yet, so unfortunately that’s not an option either.